# toggleClass when object in viewport to fire CSS3 animations

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I tried hard for days now, to make this work but I am at the end of my road, this is why I ask you for help.

I have a code snippet (below) that is able to add a class to an object, if it is in the viewport. That is perfect to fire any CSS3 animations. The code is working in chrome, local and on my remote server but firefox is only working local, so the class is added to the object but there is no transition on my remote server. All animations, that do not use the toggle class are working fine with firefox, so the css is set up correctly.

Does anybody have any idea why the code does not work in firefox, on my remote server? The code snippet is included before the body close tag.

```
    $(function () { 
    // your code here
    $.expr[':'].inViewPort = function(obj){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var top = $(obj).offset().top;
    var bottom = top + $(obj).height();
    if (top <= scrollTop || bottom <= (scrollTop + viewportHeight / 0.8)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

    });
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        $('.inview').each(function(){
            var self = $(this),
                inView = self.is(':inViewPort');
            self.toggleClass('animated', inView);
        });
    });
```

The code works like, add class "animated" to all objects with class "inview", if the object is in viewport. That suppose to start the css3 animation that was applied to the object, like "fadeInLeft".

Thanks for any idea. Also maybe someone got a better idea to fire css3 animations if the object is in viewport.

cheers
mark

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to throttle a little your scroll hander, see if that makes any difference:

```
(function () {
    var timeout;
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.inview').each(function () {
                var self = $(this),
                    inView = self.is(':inViewPort');
                self.toggleClass('animated', inView);
            });
        }, 50);
    });
}());
```

Comment: I tried and also increased the throttle but no luck. you can view and test here (if you like ;-) http://www.mark-i-mark.com/animate-test.html the top part is not using the script, it is a default css3 animation and does not depend on that script but if you scroll down, you will see "I create awesome websites" (obviousely not :-(( which suppose to be animate "tada" and the columns below, suppose to fade in from left. you can see it all working in chrome but it doesn't work in ff. any more ideas?????